# Convert to integer and get sum of two numbers

Tags: vb.net

I would like to get the sum of two numbers that are in string format such as below, but it does not work. any ideas? costDay2.Text and costDay3.Text are number values in a textbox

```
Dim Days23 As Decimal

Days23 = (Convert.ToDecimal(costDay2.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(costDay3.Text))
```

The result I get is 0.00, but the value of costDay2.Text = 150.00 and costDay3 = 200.00, so the result should be 350.00

Comment: What doesn't work? Error message?

Comment: you are converting textbox string to Decimal (good!) but then storing the sum to an integer (bad).  You'll lose the fractional portion(s).  but yea. 'it doesnt work' is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in VS 2012.  2 text boxes, costDay2, costDay3 and one command button.  At run time I input the values 2.01 and 2.50 into each text boxr espectively.  I click Button1 and get a result of 4.51 as expected

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim Day2, Day3, Day23 As Double

Day2 = costDay2.Text
Day3 = costDay3.Text
Day23 = Day2 + Day3
MsgBox(Day23)
End Sub
```

Comment: Option Strict Off = BAD BAD BAD and again BAD

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can improve your program

```vb
Dim day2, day3 as Decimal

if Not Decimal.TryParse(if(costDay2.Text.Trim() = string.Empty, "0", costDay2.Text.Trim()), day2) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid number in costDay2")
    Return
end if

if Not Decimal.TryParse(if(costDay3.Text.Trim() = string.Empty, "0", costDay3.Text.Trim()), day3) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid number in costDay3")
    Return
end if

Dim Days23 As Decimal = day2 + day3
```

This way user knows where is the bad value and if there is nothing - this is like having "0"

As far as *"The result I get is 0.00, but the value of costDay2.Text = 150.00 and costDay3 = 200.00, so the result should be 350.00"* - you might just looking at the wrong place

Comment: TryParse will set the decimal to zero if the string cannot be converted to decimal, but at least you are on the right path

Comment: @Steve :o) in this particular logic, I didn't want "tryParse" to fail if the value is empty. Because if I didn't use `If(?,True,False)` and text would be `string.empty`, `tryParse` would return `false`. I didn't want `0` if text was `abc` - this is error

Comment: ok ok , as I have said, this is a lot better than the accepted answer